# What is the error in my circuit in Simulink?

Tags: capacitor, inverter, simulink

Please see the image below. I get this error when I try to run the circuit on simulink. **Series RLC branch** and **Series RLC branch 1** refer to the two DC-Link capacitors of the inverter on the left side of the circuit. I have already tested this circuit on PSIM and it worked, so I don't understand what is wrong with it in Simulink. (I am new to Simulink).
[image]

Comment: Try putting a 1 Mohm resistor across both capacitors.

Comment: I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very abstract error... "Series RLC Branch 1"  "Series RLC Branch"  you have 6 RLC branches in this model with labels disabled (for those not familiar with SimPowerSystems, RLC is the primative, you choose the combination)

Looking at the diagram there does not appear to be any GROUND reference. This helps the "circuit" reference nodes. Not only that, you can then provide a 1Mohm to GROUND from the low side of the transformer to help the simulator resolve nodal voltages.

1. Put an EARTH node on the low side of the AC source
2. Put a 1Mohm resistor from the secondary XFMR to EARTH

if this fails please provide the simulink file so I may diagnose this end.

Comment: Tried this; didn't work. Apparently, I have to add a 1 Ohm resistor in series with each capacitor.

Comment: Real capacitors and inductors have some equivalent series resistance (ESR). I use LTSpice, and it adds a small resistance to such components if a specific value is not supplied. Zero (and infinity) can be problematic for mathematical computations as used in simulators.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have to add a 1 Ohm resistor in series with each capacitor and the circuit will work fine...
[image]

Comment: You also seem to replace your diodes with something else. Can you mention two things: 1) Why your solution works and 2) any changes you've made (other than your 1Ohm resistors because you already did that)

Comment: 1)The same diodes are actually used. The only difference is that in the previous picture I have set the Snubber Capacitance of the same diodes to 0 F, which resulted in a change in the diode symbol. I changed it from 0F to the default value because I got an error when it was set to zero.
2) I saw a video online on how half-bridge inverters are designed on Simulink, and it was mentioned in there that a a resistance had to be added to the DC link capacitors; otherwise, the Simulink will register an error. I think a 1 Ohm resistor is added to minimize the voltage drop?(I am a newbie in Simulink)